# Why does 'java .\HelloWorld' give an error but 'java HelloWorld' work in Windows Powershell?

Tags: java, powershell

I've recently started using Windows, switching from Ubuntu. I've added the `JAVA_HOME` and appropriate path variable, from my understanding both commands should give identical results?

```
PS G:\workSpace> javac .\HelloWorld.java
PS G:\workSpace> java .\HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class .\HelloWorld
PS G:\workSpace> java HelloWorld
Hello, World
```

Comment: *from my understanding both commands should give identical results* Why?  There is no class called `.\HelloWorld`.

Comment: The argument that you provide the the Java command is a fully-qualifed class name, not a file name. There is no (and there can't be a) class called `.\HelloWorld`